# PL/SQL Read Row Data From table from using Functions

Tags: sql, function, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I am fairly new to pl/sql and i'm having problems getting my function to return data from my table I don't know what to do get it to work all recommendations i have tried from browsing the web haven't been able to understand them in solving my problem

The function I created takes in an ID parameter which is used to return the name of the student matching this parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function getName(ID in INTEGER)
    RETURN varchar2
    IS id_name varchar2(25);
    BEGIN
    SELECT NAME INTO id_name from student
    where ID = getName.ID;
    RETURN (id_name);
    END;
```

The function compiles without any problem but when i try run the function with an ID value i know is the students table like this:

```
BEGIN
getName(2020001);
END;
```

I get a pls-00103 error message, i dont know what to do to get the function to read data from the student table i created any help would be appreciated

Comment: are you running this in sqlplus?  Add a / after the end of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call a function in PL/SQL, you'd generally need to declare a variable to store the return value.  And you'd probably want to do something with the result even if it is only using `dbms_output` to (potentially) write it to the console

```
declare
  l_name student.name%type;
begin
  l_name := getName(2020001);
  dbms_output.put_line( 'The name is : ' || l_name );
end;
/
```

or you can use the function in a SQL statement

```
select getName(2020001)
  from dual
```

Comment: Thanks @Justin Cave but the first code works but still doesnt fetch the data the second refuses to compile and causes a pls-00428 error as working pl/sql statements must be assigned always to variable tried an alternative  ``` select getName(2020001) into l_name
  from dual ```  the procedure then compiles successfully but doesn't return any data

Comment: @Alpheus - What does "doesn't fetch the data" mean specifically?  Are you not seeing anything written to the console?  Have you told the client to read data from the `dbms_output` buffer?  `set serveroutput on` in `SQL*Plus` for example.  As for the second, that is a SQL statement so it would be run interactively.  Not as part of a procedure.  But then I'm not sure what "doesn't return any data" means in the context of a procedure-- procedures don't return data.  They can have `out` parameters that allow them to give the caller some information but it's not obvious that's what you're doing.

Comment: yes that was the problem didnt think i needed to set serveroutput while using oralcle sql developer was able to figure it out sorry for the late reply,